# Scipy sigmoid curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have some data points and would like to find a fitting function, I guess a cumulative Gaussian sigmoid function would fit, but I don't really know how to realize that.

This is what I have right now:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, a, b):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-b*(x-a)))
     return y

xdata = np.array([400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600])
ydata = np.array([0, 0, 0.13, 0.35, 0.75, 0.89, 0.91])
         
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)

x = np.linspace(-1, 2000, 50)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='fit')
pylab.ylim(0, 1.05)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

But I get the following warning:

> .../scipy/optimize/minpack.py:779: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
> category=OptimizeWarning)

Can anyone help?
I'm also open for any other possibilities to do it! I just need a curve fit in any way to this data.

Comment: If it might be of some use, I got an excellent fit to all data points using a scaled Weibull cumulative distribution "y = Scale * (1.0 - exp(-(x/b)^a))" with R-Squared = 0.9978 and RMSE = 0.01423 using the parameters a =  6.4852359831229389E+00,  b =  1.1063972566493285E+03, and  Scale =  9.0659231615116531E-01

Comment: The link for the scipy documentation of this distribution with associated fitting details was deleted from my comment, so I am unable to assist in using scipy to fit your data - which is *how* I derived those parameter values. I do not know how you can reproduce the fitting results I posted without the deleted link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set some reasonable bounds for parameters, for example, doing

```
def fsigmoid(x, a, b):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-a*(x-b)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fsigmoid, xdata, ydata, method='dogbox', bounds=([0., 600.],[0.01, 1200.]))
```

I've got output

```
[7.27380294e-03 1.07431197e+03]
```

and curve looks like

[image]

First point at (400,0) was removed as useless. You could add it, though result  won't change much...

UPDATE

Note, that bounds are set as ([low_a,low_b],[high_a,high_b]), so I asked for scale to be within [0...0.01] and location to be within [600...1200]

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask how you came up with these bounds? Just by trial and error? And what exactly do they do?

Comment: @JohannaKöllner You're welcome. Well, not quite by trial and error. For location, it is `x` where curve would cross 0.5, so looking at the graph I selected `x` range for `y` being from approx 0.2 to 0.8. And for scale, again, it is clear it should be very small, because change in the exponent of 1 change result by roughly 3. So if we go from center of ~1100, where `y` is 0.5, and divide it by 3 (so `y` is ~0.15), and check that abscissa would be 200 apart, then it is clear scale parameter must be around .005.

Comment: @JohannaKöllner `And what exactly do they do?` Could you clarify the question? Typically `b` would be location parameter, and `a` would be scale parameter, but to get real meaning I have to know units of abscissa, what is `y`, how you collected/computed it etc.

Comment: I've done something like this before, and there were a few plots where there wasn't convergence, or it took too many iterations, so I looped over a few possibilities of starting values to find something that worked - it's also a good way of finding an average model

Answer (score 5):

You may have noticed the resulting fit is completely incorrect.
Try passing some decent initial parameters to `curve_fit`, with the `p0` argument:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata, p0=[1000, 0.001])
```

should give a much better fit, and probably no warning either.

(The default starting parameters are [1, 1]; that is too far from the actual parameters to obtain a good fit.)

Comment: Where did you get `p0=[1000, 0.001]` from? How did you determine those to be good starting parameters?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen There are two parts: from the function itself, the shift `a` is fairly easily seen to be 1000, since this is roughly the middle between the lower and upper points, and thus the inflexion point of the curve. `b` is a bit harder to eyeball, but plotting a random curve with fixed a and b over the points, varying b (in, e.g., steps of 10), will quickly give a ballpark estimate of b. So, there is a bit of manual "fitting" or eye-balling, then letting `curve_fit` take over. Familiarity with the function to be fitted helps tremendously.