# How can we fit a signal into sigmoid function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics, regression

I am working with a simple dataset and for reproducibility reasons, I am sharing it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10y6KBr5YBy0Pa0JMY_S6PD03qYoe5Tmm).

To make it clear of what I am doing - from column 2, I am reading the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

protocols = {}

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times, quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("quotient_times")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    sns.distplot(quotient, hist=False, label=protname)
```

This gives the following plots.

[image]

[image]

As we can see from the plots

- **Data-V** has a quotient of 0.8 when the `quotient_times` is less than 3 and the quotient remains 0.5 if the `quotient_times` is
  greater than 3.

How can we fit this into a sigmoid function to have a plot something like the following? I want to have the weight decreasing rapidly to zero as `quotient_times` increases.

[image]

Comment: I do not see anything resembling a sigmoid shape in your data.

Comment: Hi James, I was thinking if we set a very high value for the weight (`quotient_times`), it will fade (decay) quickly but I am stuck. Is there any way, we could at least make it look like sigmoid?

Comment: To answer your question, I personally do not see any way to do that.

Comment: Ok and thank you for your time.

Comment: your question is very unclear to me, but I think you just want something like: `1 / (1 + exp(x-5))`.

Comment: I haven't learned sigmoid functions, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786145/scipy-sigmoid-curve-fitting would be useful here