# How to improve 4-parameter logistic regression curve_fit?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, sigmoid

I am trying to fit a 4 parameter logistic regression to a set of data points in python with scipy.curve_fit. However, the fit is quite bad, see below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_4pl(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + (d-a)/(1+np.exp(-b*(x-c)))

x=np.array([2000. , 1000. ,  500. ,  250. ,  125. ,   62.5, 2000. , 1000. ,
        500. ,  250. ,  125. ,   62.5])
y=np.array([1.2935, 0.9735, 0.7274, 0.3613, 0.1906, 0.104 , 1.3964, 0.9751,
       0.6589, 0.353 , 0.1568, 0.0909])

#initial guess
p0 = [y.min(), 0.5, np.median(x), y.max()]

#fit 4pl
p_opt, cov_p = curve_fit(fit_4pl, x, y, p0=p0, method='dogbox')

#get optimized model
a_opt, b_opt, c_opt, d_opt = p_opt
x_model = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(x))
y_model = fit_4pl(x_model, a_opt, b_opt, c_opt, d_opt)

#plot
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, label="measured data")
plt.title(f"Calibration curve of {i}")
    
sns.lineplot(x=x_model, y=y_model, label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

This gives me the following parameters and graph:

```
[2.46783333e-01 5.00000000e-01 3.75000000e+02 1.14953333e+00]
```

[Graphh of 4PL fit overlaid with measured data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLT0z.png)

This fit is clearly terrible, but I do not know how to improve this.  Please help.

I've tried different initial guesses. This has resulted in either the fit shown above or no fit at all (either `warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'` error or `Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000`)

I looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786145/scipy-sigmoid-curve-fitting) and the graph produced in the accepted solution is what I'm aiming for. I have attempted to manually assign some bounds but I do not know what I'm doing and there was no discernible improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual nonlinear regresion softwares an iterative calculus is involved which requires initial values of the parameters to start. The initial values have to be not too far from the unknown correct values.

Possibly the trouble comes the "guessing" process of the initial values which might be not good enough.

In order to test this hypothesis one will try an unusal method of regression which is not iterative thus which doesn't require initial values. This is shown below.

[image]

The calculus is straightforward (with MathCad) and the results are shown below.

[image]

[image]

One have to take care about the notations which are not the same in your equation than in the above equation. In order to avoid confusion capital letters will be used in your equation while lowcase letters are used above. The relationship between them is :

[image]

Note that the sign in front of the exponential is changed to be compatible with negative c found above.

Try your nonlinear regression in starting with the above values A, B, C, D.

You should find values of parameters close to the above values but not exactly the same. This is due to the criteria of fitting (LMSE or LMSRE or LMSAE or other) implemented in your software which is different from the criteria of fitting used in the above method.

For general explanation about the method used above : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrale